# Postgres Api-rest error: SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string liter

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, api

I need to do a pokemon api in postgres from this url "https://pokeapi.co/"
The details of database (hidden.py) and the utils (myutils.py) they work right, the error is when i do in the console:

> python3 pokeapi.py

File "/home/mcala88/pokeapi.py", line 67
cur.close()
^
SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal

---

```
import psycopg2
import hidden
import time
import myutils
import requests
import json
# Load the secrets
secrets = hidden.secrets()
conn = psycopg2.connect(host=secrets['host'],
        port=secrets['port'],
        database=secrets['database'],
        user=secrets['user'],
        password=secrets['pass'],
        connect_timeout=3)
cur = conn.cursor()
defaulturl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/'
print('If you want to restart the spider, run')
print('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pokeapi CASCADE;')
print(' ')
sql = '''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pokeapi (id INTEGER, body JSONB);
print(sql)
cur.execute(sql)
# Check to see if we have ids in the table, if not add starting points
# for each of the object trees
sql = 'SELECT COUNT(id) FROM pokeapi;'
count = myutils.queryValue(cur, sql)
if count < 1:
    objects = ['pokemon', 'region', 'type']
    for obj in objects:
        sql = f"INSERT INTO pokeapi (id) VALUES ( 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/{obj}/1/' )";
        print(sql)
        cur.execute(sql, (defaulturl))
    conn.commit()
cur.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close off your triple quotes.

```
sql = '''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pokeapi (id INTEGER, body JSONB);
```

should be

```
sql = '''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pokeapi (id INTEGER, body JSONB);
'''
```